# Response is sent back very late after setting the DeferredResult setResult method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, deferred-result

I have a REST Controller, implemented using Spring MVC. The controller sets the DeferredResult setResult method with the response received after validations, from the service method.

```
df.setResult(responseobj);
```

However, the worker thread is not notified immediately after setting the response and my response is delayed.
Using the Chrome debugger I get the below message under the "Network" Tab, against my REST call.

```
"Caution: request is not finished yet"
```

However, after a wait of 2 minutes, the status updates to "200" and the response is shown.

Comment: There is no `setResponse` method in Spring [DeferredResult class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/DeferredResult.html). Are you sure about the method you are using?

Comment: Sorry, Have edited my question now. It's setResult instead of setResponse.

Comment: What is the returned value by `setResult` method?

Comment: The return is a boolean "true", which come right after that line of code it hit. My screen waits another 2 minutes to show the result.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the code, if you may upload sources of this case to github or another place I may try to help you.

Comment: I am bound by company policies and can't post my code snippet online. However, there is one thing that I have realized. My setResult() is called from inside a run method. Could that be causing some issue?